# Precision-Recall Curve Intuition for Multi-Class Classification

Tags: classification, precision-recall, multi-class, confusion-matrix, precision

I am running a CNN image multi-class classification model with Keras/Tensorflow and have established about a 90% overall accuracy with my best model trial. I have 10 unique classes I am trying to classify. However I want to present a PRC for the individual classes. I am trying to wrap my head around the intuition behind using thresholds for each class.

Since I utilize a `SoftMax` output layer activation I end up with a probability distribution for the 10 class label possibilities. If I am to create a `PRC` for this, I utilize different thresholds for each individual class and then classify the image as positive or negative depending on the probability.

Now in reality suppose I was using a threshold of `0.4` and my `softmax` activation gave me `P(dog) = .41` and `P(cat) = .42` and then small probabilities for the other classes. Thus with this threshold I am confirming my `dog` image as a `dog` even though the `softmax` probability was higher for `cat`.

Can someone explain to me how this makes sense in practice (if I were to deploy a classification model like this). My model would of course classify this image as a cat in practice since `softmax` chooses class with highest probability. What exactly is my `PRC` actually helping with when presenting evaluation metrics? Is it simply just showing how an individual class performs in the binary sense with a threshold for classification? In practice it wouldn't be using these thresholds for actual prediction.

Here is an example of what my PRC looks like for my validation set.

[image]